# Texture is being streched in a weird way

Tags: texturing, uv

I'm not sure if this is a problem with the UV Unwrapping or a problem with my model but I'm getting this weird change in the texture.

[image: Problem]

The closest I've come to fixing this is UV unwrapping based on the view (Project from view) which makes the face I was looking at perfect but the other side even more distorted. I've tried the "Minimize Strech" feature but that just made it worst, I've also tried adding geometry but that didn't improve it.

[.Blend file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1zzuBQ8ef0JqMhwGGHExpuTj2oxrTjzrW/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: if you have a Subdivision Surface modifier, maybe open Advanced > UV Smooth > Keep Corners

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Is the top face an ngon?

Comment: @moonboots didn't change anything.

Comment: @AllenSimpson nope it's a quad.

Comment: @peremil05 why don't you attach the blend file so we don't have to play a guessing game :) https://blend-exchange.com

Comment: @HarryMcKenzie done.

Comment: It looks like you are trying to use a seamless, repeatable picture to texture your file with UVs. Unless you are texturing a square plane, that's not how it works. Seamless repeatable textures are for procedural texturing, UVs are for individual and optimized texturing. Though, you can use procedural texturing and then bake it into a map that corresponds to your UVs. But either way, you have to choose what you're doing, procedural or not. What is the end goal of your model in your case?

Comment: @L0Lock looking back, this whole thread was stupid of me to create, the root problem was me not understanding UV maps, now when I have used seams the result looks much better. My prop is a chopping board so basically, any texture without artifacts would work in this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The root problem was my lack of knowledge, so if you're a beginner or just happen to make the same stupid mistake as me here is what helped me:

I've known about seams for a while now but haven't really found the point of them, I tried using seams on the model that this thread is about but did the stupid mistake of still using the "Smart UV Project" function instead of the normal UV unwrap. If you're struggling then I recommend watching a bunch of Youtube videos on UV unwrapping.

Comment: Avoiding a problem isn't the same as fixing the problem ;) Next time you need to use UVs, you might still face the same issue and not know what's wrong and how to fix it, and you can't just not use UVs all the time.

Comment: Do you have any idea what could be causing the problem @L0Lock?